# Cannot manage DB with IIS Manager

Tags: sql-server, iis-manager

I'm trying to manage my local database stored in MDF file. I was able to do that with Visual Studio 2010, but now I'm trying to use ISS manager for this purpose. I want to add database using the connection string, but just don't see this option in home page. Actually, the whole "ASP.NET" category is missing. Here's a screenshot:

[image: IIS Manager]

If I try to manually add my database using the Database Manager option, I'm getting an error:

> There was an error while performing this operation. Details:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

All components were installed using Web Platform Installer. So how am I managing my DB with IIS manager?

- Windows 7 x64 Ultimate
- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 x64
- Visual Studio 2010 Professional SP1
- IIS Manager x64

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like you've actually installed ASP.net.

Go to Control Panel/ Programs/ Windows Features and install it (under Internet Information Services/ WWW services/ Application Development Features)

Comment: Yes, this worked. Is still got some questions now on using IIS Manager itself, but I think this is a point for another question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Those questions may be better in serverfault.com